# vis.js timeline set custom background color on items without overwriting borders

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm using vis.js timeline and I'm trying to find a way to mark workhours (give them a different background). Using the [backgrundareas with groups example](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/items/backgroundAreasWithGroups.html) I have managed to get my workhours colored for specific dates.

I do not want to use the standard blue color for background, so in order to avoid this I add a class workhours. Then I can set my custom color, but then the borders of the cells are hidden unless I also set a opacity less than 1.

I have a color scheme which I'm using, so setting opacity changes the color and my workhours does not look the same in the whole application.

I'm using this code

```
.vis-item.vis-background.workhours {
    background: ##AFD9FE;
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
```

and where filterFromdate is my start date, durationDay is numbers of days in my timeline and startHour and endHour defines my working hours

```
  for (i=0; i<durationDays; i++) {
        items.add([
            {
                id: "W"+i,
                start: moment(filterFromdate).add(i, 'days').hour(startHour).valueOf(),
                end: moment(filterFromdate).add(i, 'days').hour(dayEndHour).valueOf(),
                className : 'workhours',
                type: "background"
            }
           ]);   
      }
```

this give me

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to either get my class workhours to behave like a standard vis background class (like vis-today)?

or if there is another approach to handle background on specific hours (or days)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Issue 3773](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3773) I reliased that I could set the z-index, which did the trick.

So my css ended up being

```
.vis-item.vis-background.workhours {
    background: #AFD9FE;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```